# How to Login on a website programmatically

Tags: curl, node-red

I want to programmatically log in to a website (https://www.vipmobile.rs/mojvip)

By now, the only way I figured out to input my credentials is by adding value="abcd@abc.com" on input tags trought inspect element on google chrome.
Does anyone know any way of doing this programmatically, because later in my project I would need to get page source after the user is logged in.

```
 <input data-validate="empty" placeholder="E-mail adresa" id="txt_login_username" name="UserID" value="email@abc.com" type="text">
 <input id="txt_login_password" data-validate="empty" placeholder="Lozinka" name="Password" value"password" type="password">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a way to programmatically interract with a web page and it's content, or in a way, emulate a real user : fill up fields, clic on buttons, navigate on this website and read values from it.

Of course, a better option would be using a proper API, but I doubt one is available for your purpose. 
In this case, you can still use **PhantomJS** or **CasperJS** to programmaticaly navigate on virtually any website.

Comment: Yes ,the api for this service(mobile carrier) is not available ,so im trying to figure out a way for getting bill information for more than one user , and push that data trought node red webpage(the good thing is that this website is not using any captcha service , so automation can be used) .
thank you for your help :D